# Array of integers is being saved as array of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string, yaml

I have this in my template:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_ids, multiple: true, value: 1 %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_ids, multiple: true, value: 2 %>
```

On the controllerI have this to make sure that the array is an array of integers. I tested it and it works fine :

```
before_filter :parse_json_request

  def parse_json_request
    params[:keepcon_settings_users_group][:user_ids] = params[:keepcon_settings_users_group][:user_ids].map(&:to_i) if params[:keepcon_settings_users_group][:user_ids]
  end
```

The problem is that the data is storing as a yaml but in this format:

```
---
- '1'
- '2'
```

And I need it this way:

```
---
- 1
- 2
```

My class is:

```
class UsersGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account_setting
  serialize :user_ids, Array
  attr_accessible :name, :user_ids
  after_initialize :set_defaults

  def set_defaults
    if !self.user_ids or self.user_ids == ''
      self.user_ids = []
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the incoming data from a HTML form is always sent as a string. You can fix it by calling `to_i` on each of the params like so:

```
user_ids.map!(&:to_i)
```

Comment: Im doing that here:  params[:keepcon_settings_users_group][:user_ids].map(&:to_i)

Comment: Oops - didn't see that with the long line! is the conversion working? You could try `puts params[:keepcon_settings_users_group][:user_ids].first.class.name` on the next line

Comment: Where is the YAML save happening?

Comment: The problem was the order in which I used the before filter! Thanxs Matt

Comment: Form hands me this ""1,2"  Applied this method and got: undefined method `map!' for "1,2":String